# OO Software design handling constraints - which design pattern to use?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, constraints

I'm looking at a well-known problem and therefore there has to be a design pattern or a mix of patterns to solve it.

With the following classes and properties:

CTask

- Name
- Duration
- TaskArea

CTaskArea

- Name

CPerson

- Name
- Abilities

CAbility

- Name

CTool

- Name
- CleaningTime

CConstraint

- Name
- Constraint

CTask, CPerson, CTool could have constraints e.g. Task A could only be done by persons with ability X, or person A could not do tasks of TaskArea X and so on.

For example, when I create a new CTask, CPerson or CTool I could imagine a constraint config dialog with dropdowns like:

Class   | Operator | Class | Property | Value

CPerson |  NOT     | CTool | Name     | Hammer

What design pattern provides the opportunity to dynamically configure constraints for all the classes, without forcing the classes to know additional information or take additional dependencies on each other?

Can I use an interface for objects to express that they accept constraints being applied somehow, or to discover classes which should be configurable with constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to have `contraints_for_xxx` property at each object having a constraint for particular `xxx` property?

When some child property is to be added into a collection, it is first run through constraints collection. If any constraint item returns false... exception is thrown, heaven thunders etc.

Constraints can be filled in object's constructor or later via some `setupConstraints()` call.

CPerson can look like (PHP example):

```
class Person
{
    protected $constraintsAbc = null;

    public function setConstraintsAbc(array $constraints)
    {
        $this->constraintsAbc = $constraints;
    }

    public function setABC($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->constraintsAbc as $constraint) {
            if (!$constraint->isValid($value)) {
                throw new Exception("Constraint {$constraint->getName()} is not happy with value $value");
            }
        }
        $this->abc = $value;
    }
}

class PersonSetup
{
    public function setupPerson(Person $person)
    {
        $constrains[] = new PersonAbcConstraint("Value > 5");
        $person->setContraintsABC($constrains);
    }
}
```

This is, of course, fictious example. There is a problem here in some code duplication since you have `constraintsAbc`, `setConstraintsAbc` and `setAbc` as different hard-coded fields. But you can abstract this into some virtual "constraintable" field collection if you like.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I don´t know if i fully understand it. Do you mean that a person have to know the properties of a tool and vice versa?

Comment: @user3364279 That depends on your needs. I just recommended a scheme. You can fill constraints from `Person`'s constructor (in this case, Person will know of them) or you can delegate this task to some other class (`PersonSetup` for example).

Comment: Hi FractalizeR, can you give me a little example how CPerson and CPersonSetup may look like. And do you have an idea about how a constraint-interface may look like? I may overcomplicate things a bit, but im interested in how a solution of the problem would look like, if we use interfaces or inheritance. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user3364279 Example added :)

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution im ok with:

```
class CCouldHaveConstraints_Base
{
    public virtual GetInstance();
    public virtual GetClassName();
    public virtual GetPropertyListThatCouldHaveConstraints();

}

class CPerson : CCouldHaveConstraints_Base
{
    private String m_PersonName;
    private String m_PersonAge;

    public String PersonName 
    {
        get {return this.m_PersonName;}
        set {this.m_PersonName=value;}
    }

    public String PersonAge
    {
        get {return this.m_PersonAge;}
        set {this.m_PersonAge=value;}
    }

    public override GetInstance()
    {
        return new CPerson;
    }
    public override GetClassName 
    {
        return "Person";
    }

    public list<string> GetPropertyListThatCouldHaveConstraints()
    {
            list <string> ConstraintPropsList = new list<string>;
            ConstraintPropsList.Add ("PersonName")
    }

}

// class contains a list of all objects that could have constraints
class CConstraint_Lst
{
    private list<CConstraint> m_ListOfConstraints;
    private list<CCouldHaveConstraints_Base> m_ListOfObjectsThatCouldHaveConstraints;
} 

// e.g Person | Person.Name | Tim | NOT | Tool | Tool.Name | "Hammer"
class CConstraint 
{
        private String m_ClassName_A;
        private String m_ClassProperty_A;
        private String m_ClassProperty_A_Value;
        private String m_Operator;
        private String m_ClassName_B;
        private String m_ClassProperty_B;
        private String m_ClassProperty_B_Value;
}
```

Is that enough code to figure out how im thinking?

Regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

You've already made a great conceptual leap to model the constraints as CConstraint objects. The remaining core of the question seems to be "How do I then organize the execution of the constraints, provide them with the right inputs, and collect their outputs? (the outputs are constraint violations, validation errors, or warnings)"

CConstraints obviously can't be evaluated without any input, but you have some choices on how exactly to provide them with input, which we can explore with questions:

1. Do they get given a 'global state' which they can explore and look for violations in?
2. Or do they get given a tuple of objects, or object graph, which they return a success or failure result for?
3. How do they signal constraint violations? Is it by throwing exceptions, returning results, adding them to a collection of violations, or removing violating objects from the world, or triggering repair rules?
4. Do they provide an "explanation" output that helpfully explains which object or combination of objects is the offending combination, and what rule it violates?

Compilers might be an interesting place to look for inspiration. We know a *good* compiler processes some complicated input, and produces one or more easy-to-understand error messages allowing the programmer to fix any problem in their program.

Compilers often have to choose some pattern of *organizing the work* that they're doing like recursion (recursive descent), or a visitor pattern (visit a tree of objects in some arrangement), or stateful pattern matching on a stream of input approach (syntax token recognition by regex matching, or processing a stream of characters), or a chain-of-responsibility (one processor validates and processes input, passes it to the next processor in the chain). Which is actually a whole family of design patterns you can choose from.

Probably one of the most flexible patterns to look at which is useful for your case is the visitor pattern, because you can extend your domain model with additional classes, all of which know how to do a 'visiting' phase, which is basically what 'validation' often entails - someone visits all the objects in a scenario, and inspects their properties, with an easily extensible set of logics (the validation rules) specific to those types of objects, without needing to worry about the mechanics of the visiting procedure (how you traverse the object graph) in each validation rule.